# How do I get custom inputs from entry boxes to form a specific hyperlink?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

This is my first time in coding anything and since I have to do this project soon, I couldn't have a proper tutorial in Python.

Here's the thing: I need to program a small window with two entry boxes and a button.

The button needs to add the entries into a pre-determined hyperlink. For example:

Entry 1: 2020
Entry 2: 12345

and when I click the button it should open, let's say, http://www.google.com/2020-12345.html

So far, here's where I'm at:

```
# !/usr/bin/python3  

from tkinter import *

top = Tk()

import webbrowser

new = 1
url = "http://www.google.com/e1-e2"

def openweb():
    webbrowser.open(url,new=new)

top.geometry("250x100")

name = Label(top, text="Numbers").place(x=50, y=1)

sbmitbtn = Button(top, text="Submit", command=openweb).place(x=90, y=65)

e1 = Entry(top).place(x=20, y=20)
e2 = Entry(top).place(x=20, y=45)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

# Use {} as a placeholder to allow format() to fill it in later
url_template = "http://www.google.com/{}-{}"

def openweb():
    url = url_template.format(e1.get(), e2.get())
    webbrowser.open(url,new=1)

top = Tk()
top.geometry("250x100")

# Do not use place(). It's very buggy and hard to maintain. Use pack() or grid()
Label(top, text="Numbers").pack()

# You must use 2 lines for named Widgets. You cannot layout on the same line
e1 = Entry(top)
e1.pack()
e2 = Entry(top)
e2.pack()

sbmitbtn = Button(top, text="Submit", command=openweb)
sbmitbtn.pack()

top.mainloop()
```